# Completion block method vs. DispatchQueue

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

I have implemented following completion block, one block is completed and then I update UI and object accordingly.

```
func doPaging() {
    fetchProducts(page: pageNumber , completion: { success in
        if let products = success as? Products
        {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.products.append(contentsOf:products)
                self.isWating = false;
                self.productTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    })
} 

func fetchProducts(page: Int, completion: @escaping ((AnyObject) -> Void)) {

   // URLSession call here
}
```

However, the following approach clearly shows restful call will happen in background thread and once it is completed, then update UI and objects.

```
func doPaging() {

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        // Background Thread
        fetchProducts()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.pageNumber += 1
            self.productTableView.reloadData()
            self.isWating = false            
        }
    }
}

func fetchProducts(page: Int) {

   // URLSession call here
}
```

I am confused between completion block method vs. DispatchQueue.

Which one is recommended?

Comment: Your two `doPaging` methods are not at all similar. The first calls `fetchProducts` while the second doesn't.

Comment: @rmaddy, added missing piece.

Comment: Did you try both approaches? Notice the vast difference in the order that things are executed. The best way to learn about things like this is to try. Experiment. In a case like this you will learn a lot more by experimenting than by posting a question. Once you have results you don't quite understand, then post a question asking for clarification.

Comment: If `fetchProducts` is asynchronous then go with the first option. If `fetchProducts` is synchronous go with the second.

Answer (score 1):

In the first approach, you call a method `fetchProducts()` which internally uses NSURLSession. REST call using NSURLSession runs in background and on completion of the REST call, the completion of the task will be called. In that completion, you call your completion handler of `fetchProducts()`. This approach seems fine to me.

In the second approach, you use global background queue and asynchronously call NSURLSession APIs (I assume so), and don’t wait for the call to complete. The code on main queue will be instantly called and at this point the NSURLSession task **may or may not** have been completed. 
So, this approach is problematic.

Comment: "*the NSURLSession task may or may not have been completed*" - the URLSession won't even be started yet.

Answer (score 1):

> Completion block and Dispatch Queue are two different concepts.

Completion block is used when your function perform actions takes time to run, and need to return back and run some code even the functions has "ended". For example,

```
func networkCall(foo: Int, completion:@escaping (_ result:Bool)-> Void))
func otherFunc(){...}
func A(){
   networkCall(foo:1){ (success) in
       // handle your stuff
   }
   otherFunc()
}
```

When you run A(), it first run networkCall(), however networkCall() may takes time to run the network request and the app **moved on to run otherFunc()**. When the network request is done, networkCall() can call it's **completion block** so that A() can handle it again.

Dispatch Queue is the threading stuff safely encapsulated by Apple. Network request can be performed in Main thread as well, but it will be blocking other functions.

A common practice is to call Network request in background queue 
`DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async` and call **completion block** after finished. If anything needs to be updated in main thread like UI, do it in the `DispatchQueue.main.async`

Answer (score 1):

First method seems OK as long as you fetchProducts asynchronously. In fetchProducts() , if you call the completion block in the main queue you won't even need to get main queue again in the doPaging() method.

In your second method, you are calling fetchProducts() in a global (concurrent) queue. Although global queues start each task in the order they were added to queue, they run tasks concurrently. And since fechtProduct() takes time, your code block that contains `self.pageNumber += 1` executed before even fetchProduct's URLSession is started. So, this approach won't work.